# How is the path of the ROOT POM file using Jenkins?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, jenkins

Hi I'm trying to run build in Jenkins using Maven project. Every time I'm trying to use the full path to my pom.xml I got error. The only way to make it work is to copy my pom.xml from my eclipse project to the workspace that Jenkins use and to set 
**ROOT POM = pom.xml**

Is this mean that every time a change something in my automated scripts in eclipse project I have to copy the pom.xml to the Jenkins' workspace?

If there is more convenient way can you share it with me.

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins you have application poms and ROOT POM.

**- Application pom.xml:**

The pom.xml is in this path:

```
.jenkins\jobs\jenkinsJobName\workspace\YOURAPP\pom.xml
```

**- ROOT POM**

The ROOT POM is in this PATH:

```
$workspace\pom.xml
```

For Unix systems is:

```
$workspace/pom.xml
```

Comment: But how to set up it properly. I set Build > ROOM POM = pom.xml. How to tell Jenkins to take pom.xml from my eclipse project and not to copy it every time? Also what to do with this Application pom.xml I don't understand?

Comment: Do you have your jenkins in the same machine of your Eclipse?

Comment: My Jenkins is on: /Users/Shared/Jenkins and my Eclipse is on: /Users/enislavmollov/Documents/Maven workspace/MavenProkect....When I was installing Jenkins I wasn't able to select different destination so that is default installation folder of Mac.

Comment: You need to put in Jenkins the path to your Eclipse pom.xml. ./Users/enislavmollov/Documents/Maven workspace/MavenProkect/pom.xml  or .\Users\enislavmollov\Documents\Maven workspace\MavenProkect\pom.xml depending of your system.

Comment: Both ways give me No such file: ‘/Users/enislavmollov/Documents/Maven workspace/MavenProkect/pom.xml’